# Fetch single record in a table having duplicate values using Linq

Tags: c#, linq

Table structure:

[image: Table structure image]

I want to fetch records as below:

[image: Expected results image]

So the address should follow this order:

```
Mail
Home
Work
```

If `Mail` is present pick the record else if check if `Home` is present then pick the record and else if check if `Work` is present then pick that record.

Comment: Why is it _Mail_ for Bipin? What should it be for Mahesh and why?

Comment: I want to pick the records on below priority First it should pick Mail then Home and then Work    In above scenario Bipin has all the three address Mail Home and Work. So Bipin with Mail should be picked up.     For Mahesh we have only two address Home and Mail so for Mahesh Mail should be picked up. Similary for Paresh only work is present so Work should be picked up

Comment: I can't see any _priority_ column in your tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define your priority first.

In order to do this you can use a simple `Dictionary<string, int>`:

```
var AddressMap = new Dictionary<string, int>(){
    {"Mail", 0},
    {"Home", 1},
    {"Work", 2}
};
```

After this, you can simply order by this dictionary:

```
employees.OrderBy (e => AddressMap[e.Address]) //order 
         .GroupBy (e => e.Id)
         .Select (e => e.FirstOrDefault());
```

Output:

[image]

Complete Example in Linqpad:

[http://share.linqpad.net/et3j2g.linq](http://Linq%20order%20by%20dictionary)